# VSCode and Path Error in an Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, since few days, Intellisense stop to underline wrong path file in my code.

And when I put the mouse over the wrong line, it displaying "module '*'" :

[image: Wrong path]

How to (re)activate this?

I add more informations : here is my tsconfig :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

User settings in VSCode :

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.js": {"when" : "$(basename).ts"},
        "**/*.js.map": true
    }

}
```

Comment: We need a bit more info, as in: are you using js ou ts, what is in your tsconfig/jsconfig, etc...

Comment: I add my tsconfig file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've comment this line in the file `typings.d.ts`

`declare module '*';`

It's ok now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the "module" property in your tsconfig.

Comment: Can you tell me a little bit more? I'm new with ts

Comment: I add `"module": "es5",` but same result

Comment: I've try all valus but no success